# What kind of 24 inch bmx is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

I have a 24 inch bmx and have no clue what it is. I need help please!!!

[image][image]

Comment: I believe it's a bicycle.... a blue one.

Comment: Does the rear wheel coast or is it a fixed speed ?

Comment: @RoboKaren - Are you sure it's blue?  I'd tend to call it "aqua".

Comment: It might be black and gold depending on the light.

Comment: We're kidding around a bit, but the net-net is that it's a generic kid's BMX, likely produced in some anonymous Chinese factory and fitted out in another with decals to suit Walmart or whoever eventually sold it.  Was never anything expensive, but it might at one time have been equipped with Batman or Princess Sofia decals and other accouterments -- whatever would catch the eye of a kid.  (Though such embellishments would be more likely on a 20 inch bike.)

Comment: There is one point that makes the bike unusual, and perhaps a step up from the typical BSO -- the three-piece crank.

Comment: And the yellow-painted rear hub is also unusual, though I can't tell if that's after-market.

Answer (score 5):

Its a generic BMX that has been ridden by a rider too big for it - the handlebars are leaned away from the saddle

Likely its been stripped of both brake systems - I can clearly see cable lugs under the top tube, and some kind of brake mount on the seat stay right by the tyre.

The tread pattern differs significantly between wheels, with the front being much knobblier.   I suspect one has been replaced and not the other.  Doesn't mean anything much.

Can't really tell if its been painted over or not.  There are no visible decals or badges in your photos, so its quite hard to say more.

I suggest you fit brakes as per your local law's requirements, give it some maintenance, and enjoy riding your new blue bike.

*Knowing the brand is a bit like knowing the parents of a mongrel/pound dog.... Knowing won't change the dog one bit.*

Comment: No decals and the general state. If you bought it, make sure it has not been stolen.

Comment: Just because it has cable lugs does not say it ever had brake cables.  (Though I guess the unused brake lever on the handlebar suggests that there was once some sort of hand brake.)

Comment: > Knowing won't change the dog one bit. --  Except for in BMX, knowing the brand will let you know what material the frame could be. It's generally good practice to avoid High-ten steel frames (within the bmx community).

Answer (score -1):

It's not 24 inches. of 20-in BMX Hoffman bike that's been through a lot of changes.

I'm only 30 and I know my bikes.

There's a 20 inch not a 24.

Change the grills out for 2x 20-in rims and throw those 24-in rims out in the trash.

There's a three piece crank. That's mountain bike parts.

Mike's don't have those 20 inches only, right now.

It is not x games 20-in bike.

It's a Matt Hoffman.

Comment: Welcome. It would help if you could separate your sentencese, best using full stops, to make your statement clearer. It is really hard to understand (though I am not a native English speaker).

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This is very difficult to follow, but you seem to be identifying it as originally a 20" Mat Hoffman bike.  Which one?  A picture showing a bike matching the frame proportions and visible details of the one in the question will go a long way to making this a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

This is most likely a contract bike, made by one company for another. My best guess is that it was made for the "XGames" brand by "WeThePeople". ESPN own the XGames brand, but does not make mikes. They originally contracted with Tony Hawk to make skateboards and Mat Hoffman to make BMX bikes.

Criggie had some good points, it was spray painted (they didn't remove the headset cups or the sprocket before painting it) and it is NOT a major brand BMX. You can tell by a few key points. The forks are 1" threaded with a "Wedge down the Tube" neck rather than 1-1/8" threadless. The rear axle is 3/8" rather than 14mm. It came with pegs already on the bike, larger dropouts and the washers are missing (pegs act as the washers, hence the lack of washers once removed, and major bikes don't usually sell you bikes with pegs, they expect you to supply your own). The seatstay is pinched to fit a larger front sprocket. No welded Gyro bosses. The headset and bottom bracket are not using sealed bearings (you can see by the adjustment slots in the BB cone) and the headtube does not use an integrated bearing cup.

I can't find any pictures of this particular bike, but this is why I am pretty sure it was made for "XGames" by WeThePeople. Here is an image of a recent XGames FS20:
[image: FS20 by XGames]

This is not the same year as your bike, so there are some differences: the downtube is curved, the brakes are more like V-Brakes (bosses are lower than the rims) rather then the 990s (like yours, up by the tire). Now lets focus on the similarities:
3/8" axles, seatstay/chainstay taper at the rear welds, seatstay/toptube welds at the seattube, the style of the pinch in the chainstay tube by the sprocket. Now for the parts that could have been changed, but most likely not (any why I think it is an XGames contract bike) the seatpost, seatguts, reflector, seat clamp, brake lever are all the same, and the seat on your bike says "FS20" which is not the brand of the bike but rather the brand of the parts maker. Contracted bikes will often use the same parts company even if they change frame welders.

Now let look at why I think the frame was contracted with WeThePeople:
[image: We The People Curse FS 20 2017]

This is a 2017 "Curse FS20" by WeThePeople. There are differences: they used a 14mm rear axle, the smaller sealed bottom bracket, smaller front sprocket so no pinch in the chainstay, integrated headset cups, welded Gyro bosses. Now for the similarities: same rear tube taper at the welds, the same bend from the bottom bracket around the tire, same tube cut shapes for the seatstay and toptube at the seattube, reinforcement gussets on the toptube and downtube at the headtube, and the brake bosses are at the same spots as on your bike. Why is this last part important? Most companies will use the same jig for their bikes, for welding.

This is just an educated guess, and since it is not made by a major bike company, there is not really any website to find for them.

And here is the crossbar on the seatstays
[image: The crossbar on the seatstays of the original bike]

This is NOT a "Curse FS20" by WeThePeople, I am guessing it is from the "XGames" line, but not sure the year or model.

Comment: And the seat stays of the bike in the question are completely different from the Curse FS20 (the Curse has a cross-member just above the tyre, whihc the bike in the question doesn't). I'm honestly not sure how to evaluate this: as you say, there are many similarlities but there are also many differences.